# are own [sections] in my.conf ok?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i am reinventing the wheel by writing a backup script to dump mysql databases. It is just an exercise. Therefore I am wondering, if i can add own sections to my.conf e.g.

```
[backup]
backupdir = /backup/mysql/
```

Could this cause a problem to the config?

Comment: You would have to check the manual. Basically you need to know if MYSQL or its processors are going to even look at anything you invent in the `ini` file

Comment: i want to use the ini file to put additional information

Comment: Yes I get that. But the point is MySQL or its command line tools will only look at what they look at in the `ini` file. You can add anything you like in there, but if it is never going to be looked at......whats the point

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks _You can add anything you like in there, but if it is never going to be looked at_ exactly answered my question. i want this sections read by a script and use their in the context of backup that data bases. thats the point. since i need other information from this config file it would be nice to have some others there too...

Comment: But why....why you doesn't just create another `ini` file?

Comment: @Hackerman, there are thousands of options. at the moment I have the settings for the scripts in a different `ini` file. the credentials to connect the database are taken from the `my.ini` and backup settings from another. this works perfect. it is just pure curiosity, if this is possible or if this would cause any drawbacks.... there could be also the question why each section does not have a different `ini` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add own sections. This file is meant to to extensible.
Would I recommend it? Not sure. Even if today [backup] section is not used, tomorrow (in a year, in a decade) in some future version of Maria/MySQL it might be used by something else than your own utility.